# Javascript Regular Expression to match several criteria

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a javascript regular expression that will match the following criteria -

- Must contain 8 - 15 characters
- Combination of letters (UpperCase OR LowerCase) and numbers (Special characters are allowed, but NOT mandatory)
- Not more than 2 repeating characters

Thanks in advance!

I have tried the following but seems not to be working -

```
/^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-])\1{2})(?=.*\d){8,15}$/
```

Comment: You will get good answers if you show your attempt in question.

Comment: Added what I have tried with, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(?!.*?(.)\1{2})(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]).{8,15}$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD6fY3/9)

This will enforce these rules:

1. Length between 8 to 15
2. At least one Upper/Lower case letter
3. A Digit
4. Not more than 2 repeats

Comment: That's not what he asked for: (1) special characters are missing and (2) he wants to allow characters repeating twice, like `aa` but not `aaa`

Comment: Thanks, corrected 2 repeats. It already allows special characters, OP said `NOT mandatory`

Comment: Try your regex with simply `123456789012345`: for me it doesn't work (15 non-repeated digits). I don't know if it's regex101 or what, but if you put it alone, it won't match, while it will if you insert the other strings, too (in new lines)

Comment: `123456789012345` won't match because my regex is checking for one 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase letter (see rules above)

Comment: Yeah, my bad :) sorry!

Comment: UpperCase is not mandatory for me, but user can use upper case letters. Other criteria do match here. Please suggest how can I modify the regex to match that.

Comment: I have modified the expression as -
/^(?!.*?(.)\1{2})(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]).{8,15}$/gm 
and it seems to be fulfilling all the criteria. Thanks. :)

Comment: I just updated the regex and it seems you also got the same one :)